# SilverStripe - caching silverstripe-blocks with cacheinclude

Tags: caching, block, silverstripe

We're using the module https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks and want to make use of https://github.com/heyday/silverstripe-cacheinclude, has anybody successfully integrated the two?

Comment: The problem is when we have more than one of the same block type on a page, so for example we have two 'ImageBlock' on the home page. The template for this block is entirely wrapped in <% cache 'ImageBlock' %>. Cacheinclude has been setup via YML with context: 'page', and contains the relevant models. This results in the 2nd block having the same content as the 1st block.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping all your blocks into a cache block instead? Eg. `<% cache 'Blocks' %><% loop $Blocks %>…<% end_loop %><% end_cache %>` ?

Comment: But how will I know what blocks each page is going to contain? or would you suggest putting 'Blocks' as the contains model rather than the subclasses? Guess the only downside of that will be that changes to any blocks on any page will invalidate the cache for all blocks?

Comment: I guess the cache rule should contain all block-classes… then saving one of them will invalidate the cache, but that's not too big of an issue, is it?